# I am trying to create a Login page for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to reference a database with sql to compare it to the text boxes, I do not know why my code is not working, its probably my IF statement? It could be that I am not writing the SQL statement correctly also.

```
Protected Sub btnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM loginInfo"

    If "SELECT UserName, PassCode From loginInfo Where [UserName] [PassCode]" Then
        Response.Redirect("gridView.aspx")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you should fix the formatting

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things wrong here:

1. Your query syntax is incorrect.
2. You don't need to load all the users on page load. Just checking the entered username and password will do.

On a side note, use parameterised queries to avoid SQL Injection.

What you can do is this - in the `btnValidate_Click` method, get your entered username and password, pass it to the query and if you find a record with username and password matching the user entered text, consider it as a successful login and redirect to the required page. Code would be something like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

Protected Sub btnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
 Dim recordMatch as int
 Using con As New OleDbConnection( _
  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("DynamicDataBase.mdb")),
  con.Open()
  Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM loginInfo WHERE [UserName] = @username AND [PassCode] = @passcode"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, con)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = yourusernametextbox.Text
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@passcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = yourpasscodetextbox.Text     
  recordMatch = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
 End Using

 If recordMatch = 1 Then
    Response.Redirect("gridView.aspx")

 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting an error, "Using con".  It says Variable 'con' hides a Variable in an enclosing block.

Comment: Oops, my bad, remove the `Dim con as..` statement.

Comment: oh ok, last error "con.Open" is says and "Local Variable 'con' already declared in current block" then "end of statement expected"

Comment: OK fixed code. Sorry for that, but I wasn't able to properly test the code earlier :)